# PHP: How to parse JSON data

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

i am trying to send JSON data to PHP server, but i can understand how can i parse my JSON in PHP and insert values in Mysql database.

Here is how looks my JSON data

```
 {"reps_list":{"selected_subcategory_id":[0,1,2]}}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$reps_list = $_POST['reps_list'];
$reps_list= json_decode($reps_list,TRUE);

 for($i = 0; $i <= count($array['reps_list']['selected_subcategory_id']); $i++){
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO reps VALUES(NULL, '".$array['reps_list']['selected_subcategory_id'][i]."', 1, 1 )");
```

}

Any Suggestions?

Comment: it is not valid json, post you valid json

Comment: If that was valid JSON data then you'd use [`json_decode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), but it's not so you can't.

Comment: i have edited my question and paste VALID json ))

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability. You should use parameters in your query, instead of interpolating variables into your SQL string.  `json_decode()` does not protect values.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this for your **valid** json, decode the string as `array` using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter **true** to make it array and then treat it as an array before using it on db query.

```
$array = json_decode('{"reps_list":{"selected_subcategory_id":[0,1,2]}}',1);
echo "Main Array after json string decode \n\n";
print_r($array); 
echo "\n\n";
echo "Access selected_subcategory_id \n\n";
print_r($array['reps_list']['selected_subcategory_id']);
```

**Output:**

**Main Array** after json string decode

```
Array
(
    [reps_list] => Array
        (
            [selected_subcategory_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 1
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Access **selected_subcategory_id**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

**DEMO**: https://eval.in/975261

Answer (score 1):

Since you've updated your post with the intention to `INSERT` it into the database, here is what will work:

```
$reps_list = $_POST['reps_list'];
$json = json_decode($reps_list,TRUE);

$arr = $json['reps_list']['selected_subcategory_id'];

$insertWorkout = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO reps (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$insertWorkout->bind_param("iii", $arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]); // iii means they are all integers
$insertWorkout->execute();
```

Comment: thanks for answer,  have updated my question, i want to insert data in LOOP, but when i am running the code, throws exception like this `Undefined index: i`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
foreach($reps_list['selected_subcategory_id'] as $key => $value){

mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO reps VALUES(NULL, '".$value."', 1, 1 )");

}
```

Comment: throws this exception `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$key' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/asata/public_html/etsports/data/add_reps.php on line 28`

Comment: you can try now